# Custom BSON serialization Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson, ruby-module

How to implement custom BSON serialization for a class in Ruby using the Mongo Ruby Driver ?

There is an `as_extended_json` method in `BSON::Object` module, mentioned in
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON%2FObject:as_extended_json

I tried to include this module and override this method, but it does not get called automatically, while inserting the object in the Mongo database.

Can you even override a module method in an including class ?

Comment: `BSON::Object` is already included in Object when you require BSON. (You don't need to include it yourself).  You just need to define the method `as_extended_json` in your class. *"Subclasses should override this method to provide custom serialization to Extended JSON."* Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: my class structure is currently not bson-translatable, need to provide custom serialization.

Comment: Can you you show code as to how you are "inserting the object in the Mongo database"? Are you using an ORM like mongoid?